# Tumblr data-urlencoded-name definition

Tags: tumblr, tumblr-themes

What is `data-urlencoded-name`? I see it in the Tumblr themes but can't seem to find a definition anywhere. If someone could point me in the right direction, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

```
<body data-urlencoded-name="{URLEncodedName}"></body>
```

This attribute is specific to the [Tumblr Official Theme](https://www.tumblr.com/theme/37310). The value is `URLEncoded` string of the blogs `{name}` variable.

```
mike@home -> mike%40home
mike did this -> mike+did+this
```

More information on [Variable Transformations](https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#variable-transformations).